# Storing boolean mask in TFRecords

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

since a boolean only represent a bit, is there an efficient way to serialize a boolean mask inside a tfrecord and can be deserialized in pure tensorflow?

For now I'm converting it to `int` and encode it to `png` which is better than serializing the `int64` list, and is convenient as I can use `tf.image.decode_png` which is pure tensorflow.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184812/tensorflow-is-it-possible-to-store-tf-record-sequence-examples-as-float16 This link might help.  Note the comment by Hawkins.